# Margin в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь сделать анимацию движения элемента вверх в ConstraintLayout'e.
Для этого делаю так:

`TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
 applyConstraintSet.setMargin(R.id.bernoullis, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
 applyConstraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)`

После такого элемент просто исчезает. Грешил на TransitionManager. Но без него все так же. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ларчик просто открывался.
Необходимо правильно инициализировать переменную. Работающий код:

`applyConstraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
applyConstraintSet.setMargin(R.id.bernoullis, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
applyConstraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)`